# Could Not Launch Appium Inspector

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, appium, ios-ui-automation

Guys how to overcome from this problem while launching the iOS app from appium server, unable to open appium inspecter
please help me out to come out of the group guys.

this below warning message from in the pop up

Be sure the Appium server is running with an application opened by using the "App Path" parameter in Appium.app (along with package and activity for Android) or by connecting with selenium client and supplying this in the desired capabilities object.

please help me out to come out of the group guys.

Comment: you should probably share more details over the appium configurations used and serve logs.

Answer (score 1):

Build the app through XCode, and then specify path to the app, you should be able to find it through XCode.

**Update**

I had the same problem a while, here is how I solved it:

1. Build the application on your Mac using Xcode Simulator
2. Find location of the app on your machine, [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171752/ios-simulator-installed-app-location-in-xcode-6-1) is how to do it
3. Enter the path in Appium GUI
4. Now you should be able launch inspector

Some additional information:

1. My old blog on how to setup [Appium GUI](http://ninjawebzen.com/how-to-set-appium-test-on-ios-simulator/)
2. Blog on how to start using Appium [tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-appium--cms-23861)

Comment: Hi @slav.can you able to give more details in specific so that I can overcome from the problem

Comment: Hi, I just updated the original answer, hope it helps.

Comment: ..thanks for your informaton ..let me try to with your steps.I will try on mac and I will update further ..Thank you Slav Kurochkin

Comment: Am using real device ..Can you please give the stepas..I have the .ipa file and device 6+ has provisioning  profile set by developer where in I can install the app

Comment: Below is the lof of  the appium

Answer (score 0):

Appnium can only recognized .app file. It cannot open the .ipa file.

Comment: No way, it opens .ipa files too. Its working on my fellow's mac just not on mine. May be I have installed ruby etc. several times which is why things got mingled.