# Could not launch the appium inspector

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, automation, mobile-application, appium-ios

I tried following the suggestions provided in this post **0**:
[Could Not Launch Appium Inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549530/could-not-launch-appium-inspector)

but I still have no luck. I am not able to launch the appium inspector.

1. Could someone elaborate on how to build my app in the XCODE when I have '.ipa' file for the application that I downloaded from the app store? -- (this was mentioned in one of the solutions from the post tagged above.)

2.This is the error printed in the console when i tried following the suggestions from the above post and providing the app path to the Appium GUI. Screenshot is attached below.

[image: Appium Console Print]

[image: GUI Configuration]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect elements of ios simulator by using accessibility inspector from the xcode or you have to get pagesource and find the required elements.

You can use the ios inspector in the below link.

https://github.com/mykola-mokhnach/Appium-iOS-Inspector